# Setting Tor Browser as default in Linux

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, linux

I actually have a two part question, but the first may answer the second...

I am running an OpenSuSE Leap 42.2 Linux system with the KDE desktop. Is there a way to set the Tor Browser as my default browser for handling .html files? I have tried a few things in a fashion similar to the way Firefox was configured but it appears that the Tor Broswer is being launched via scripts that don't follow the same rules.

My second question is related, how do I configure Thunderbird to launch and/or use the Tor Browser rather than Firefox? My attempts so far seem to result in a failure especially if I have a Tor Browser already opened and running.

Thanks in advance for any and all offers to help guide me along... Darkstar

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to set the Tor Browser as my default browser for handling .html files?

Tor Browser makes it deliberately hard to set it as the default browser. There are some privacy concerns. Take a look at ticket [#12763](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/12763) and `torbrowser-launcher`'s issue [#157](https://github.com/micahflee/torbrowser-launcher/issues/157).

Answer (score 0):

A workaround is to set your default browser to a shell script that copies the text into the clipboard (and notifies you). This allows you to simply paste the URL into Tor, instead of it automatically opening up in an insecure browser. Here's mine:

```
#!/bin/sh

if [[ $# -eq 0 ]] ; then
    echo "Usage: cpnotif [text to copy]"
    exit 1
fi

echo -n $1 | xclip -selection clipboard 
notify-send "Text copied!" "$1 copied to clipboard."
```

xclip and notify-send required.